# Dividing a model by intersecting geometry parts

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I want to "cut" my building model. This means creating edges everywhere where plane (or multiple planes) intersects with faces of my model. This is similar to 'Edge loop and slide' tool.
[image]

But 'Edge loop and slide' works only for primitive models unfortunately. My model is more complicated. Does blender have described tool? Or maybe someone knowns good addon for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use Boolean Modifier. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans

Comment: edge loop and slide works for complicated meshes so long as you maintain all quads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Intersect Tool added in 2.72 will cut up intersecting faces - this is for meshes that are part of the same object, not multiple intersecting objects and can be found in Mesh->Face->Intersect.

[Campbell explains it in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rwvxusuJXU)

There are a couple of addons that can help with boolean operations.

One is [Blender sculpt tools](https://github.com/MadMinstrel/blender-sculpt-tools) - the name is a bit misleading as it also works outside of sculpt mode.

Another is [BoolTool](https://github.com/vitorbalbio/code.git)

Comment: Intersect tool is exactly what I'm looking for if I keep 'Separate' checkbox unchecked. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bisect tool in Edit mode. The plane is defined by two points and your current camera direction.

Comment: Is there a way to snap or lock the bisect tool to horiz or vert lines to make an accurate cut in an ortho view? when i tried i had to resort  to eyeball grid.